# MVVM clear textbox in the view model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

Im trying to clear data that is being stored in a text box in the view model
I am able to clear this in the view xaml using .clear; but i dont want to use code behind

```
<TextBox Name ="UserFirstName" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="23" Margin="119,67,0,0" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding User.FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="163" TextChanged="UserFirstName_TextChanged"/>
```

I want the fields to refresh each time the page is clicked on

Any suggestions

Comment: Please show some code

Answer (score 1):

The `Text` property of your textbox should be bound to a property in the viewmodel.

When you change the value of the property in the viewmodel then the text in the text box will just update automatically through data binding.

Comment: in the question Text *is* bound to a view model (`Text="{Binding User.FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`)

Comment: s there a way i can clear this through a  button clik

Comment: Your button should be bound to a `RelayCommand` in the viewmodel, expose this through an ICommand property in the viewmodel, and bind the `Command` property of the button to that.  When it is invoked, just clear the text in the viewmodel property.

Answer (score 1):

The text is bound to a property `User.FirstName`. To ensure data binding works, the property has to raise `PropertyChanged` event:

```
public class UserViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     private string _firstName = "";
     public string FirstName
     { 
         get { return _firstName; }
         set { _firstName = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
     }

     public event PropertyChanged;

     private void OnPropertyChanged( [CallerMemberName] string propertyName )
     {
          PropertyChanged?.Invoke( this, new PropertyChanedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
     }
}
```

MVVM relies on `INotifyPropertyChanged` to notify the XAML UI about changed in the data bound view model instances.

So now, once you want to clear the `FirstName`, you just assign `string.Empty` to it and the UI will automatically update.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code (corrected version of)

> Martin Zikmund

```
public class UserViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged{
    private string _firstName = "";
    public string FirstName{ 
        get {
            return _firstName;
        }
        set {
            _firstName = value; OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged( [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null ){
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
    }
}
```